# PHP widget in Wordpress is not fitting within borders

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

The Follow&share widget on the left sidebar is an executable php plugin but for some reason it's not fitting within the box.  I've used CSS for widget title but just used borders to surround each widget in the style.css sheet.
http://2010.pivotcon.com/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` links contained inside the widget div are floated, so you need to clear the float before the end of the container inside which you want the links to appear. In this case, it could be solved by placing a `<br/>` with the clear after the div, you can see it in this screenshot (I marked the added `<br/>`):

[image: screenshot with added markup to solve the problem]